# In drupal 8 how i can create 410 page status for my pages unpublished

Tags: php, http-headers, drupal-8, http-status-code-410, symfony-http-foundation

For unpublished pages, the current behavior is a 404 error,
I wish to have an 410 error only for the pages which were previously published and subsequently unpublished.

Is it feasible ?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like this module may be able to do it, if you use content moderation. https://www.drupal.org/project/archived_410

Comment: and it will work for the unpublish page ?

Comment: I have not used it myself. It was just something I found when I was looking for an answer, and I thought it looked similar enough to what you were trying to do that it might be adapted for your purposes.

Comment: I tested this but unfortunately does not work as I want
Thank you anyway.

Comment: You could use redirects, where you tell drupal to redirect those links to your 410 link.

Comment: by using hook_node_operations, within that hook you can define rules to run when a node is being unbublished (but this hook on D7 not sure about D8.x and later [im assuming they have a similar replacement hook]).